# Python desktop notifer, no notification pop up?

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import time
import requests
from plyer import notification

covidDATA = None# no data intilly
try:
    covidDATA = requests.get('https://corona-rest-api.herokuapp.com/Api/india')
except:
    print(' Please ! check your internet connection')

if covidDATA != None:
    # converting data to JSON format( for easier reading)
    data = covidDATA.json()['Success']

    while True:
        notification.notify(
            # title for notification
            title = 'COVID19 stats on {}'.format(datetime.date.today()),
            # body of the notification
            message = 'Total cases = {totalcases}\nToday cases : {todaycases}\nToday deaths :{todaydeaths}\nTotal active:{active}'.format(
                        totalcases = data['cases'],
                        todaycases = data['todayCases'],
                        todaydeaths = data['todayDeaths'],
                        active = data['active']),
            # ceating icon for notfications
        app_icon = 'alarm-bell_icon-icons.com_68596.ico',
            # time for notifications to stay
        timeout = 50
        )
    # time for repeat
        time.sleep(60*60*4)
```

I can see the icon showing up but there are no notifications, even after clicking on the icon no notifcations pop up, i am a learner and don't know alot about the modules., how can the notifications be seen .

Comment: Check your action center. Most likely the notifications are piling up there. Sometimes notification goes to action centre in case silent hour is active or some app is running in full screen mode. If you can see your notification there your code is working fine. Just disable the silent hour or exit from the full screen.

Comment: On a second check, there is another problem with your code though. You are checking for covid data only once in the beginning. Therefore all the notifications will have same data. You need to change your logic little bit.